# Call to a member function exec() on a non-object error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, exec

```
function add_member($idmembers, $firstname, $lastname,  $email, $phone, $level, $password) {
global $db;
$query = "INSERT INTO members
             (idmembers,  first, last, email, phone, level, password)
          VALUES
                ($idmembers,  '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$phone', '$level', '$password')";
var_dump($query);
$db->exec($query);

}
```

This code gives me this error and information from the var dump:

> string(224) "INSERT INTO members (idmembers, first, last, email, phone, level, password) VALUES (, 'Gina', 'Hill', 'hill@me.com', '7778889898', 'm', '803591803e3d6e646cd3ee4a35fee6dd')"
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function exec() on null in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\WEBSITE\register.php on line 26

I've checked adding the query to the database to make sure the query is working and it works fine.

Comment: bright as daylight `VALUES (, 'Gina', '` missing first argument

Comment: This is a auto-increment ID field. The ID automatically inserts a number when I try it in the database without adding anything, just using this query.

Comment: And `var_dump()` is the right idea, but rather try to debug what `$db` actually is. (By the error message it's not a database handle.)

Comment: @ReginaShepherdRiddle it doesn't matter if its an auto increment field, its a syntax error, either leave it behind including the corresponding field or provide a `null` in it

Comment: I tried it using NULL and it still won't work. Sorry - Wish it would have.

Comment: Did you try changing `exec` to `query`?

Comment: I tried using a var_dump on $db but it just says NULL in XAMPP. I didn't put it on the server yet.

Comment: @ReginaShepherdRiddle make sure you connect right, `$db` should be a `PDO object`, just as eloquently stated in the answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Tried and it says the same thing - NULL or call to member function exec() on a non object when it's on the server. I wish it would have worked.

Comment: @Ghost My connection works for getting data from the database, so I'm sure the connection is working.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag - For example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and the rest of your code, see if it yields anything.

Comment: My professor worked on this for a while and couldn't figure it out. If you can figure it out, I'll be SO HAPPY!!! Thanks. There has to be a answer!!!

Comment: What is the value that you're passing for `$idmembers`?

Comment: I tried the error reporting even though my error reporting is working already... it gives the same error as displayed above. Thanks for trying!!!

Comment: @Fred-ii_ I tried it with $idmembers where $idmembers is set to '' a empty string and NULL

Comment: @Fred-ii- if I try inserting the query, it auto-increments fine with just the empty string as far as the database goes.

Comment: If your column is set to auto_increment, just remove `$idmembers,` from the function and `$idmembers,` from your values. If you're wanting to enter an id for it in your function, it won't work. That's what AI is for, and will not accept a parameter for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok. I took out the idmembers from the query and it still won't work, but thank you so much!!! God bless you for trying.

Comment: You're welcome Regina.

Comment: If `$db` is `null`, that means it's simply not an active database connection object. Where and how are you creating `$db`? That's what you need to investigate!

Comment: @deceze - the thing is, the same way that I use this, I use $db in another file to extract data from the database and it works: Here is the code that works:global $db;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tires WHERE idtiremodel = 26 ORDER BY idtires ASC");
$query->execute();

$tires = $query->fetchAll();

Comment: It's honestly irrelevant if it works elsewhere. Figure out why it doesn't work *in this case*. We cannot investigate this further, because we don't see the relevant code. The only thing we can tell you with certainty is: `$db` is not a database object, that's the cause of your error message. Figure out why it's not. Figure out why you think it *should* be.

Comment: @deceze What should I post in order for you to help? My database connection file without the username and password in it? Thanks

Comment: <?php
 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost" OR $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "127.0.0.1") {
  // login locally
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=regina_tires';
  $username = '';
  $password = ''; 
  echo "connected";
 } else {
  // login online 
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=regina_tires';
  $username = '';
  $password = '';
  echo "connected to server";
 }
 
 try {
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  include('database_error.php');
  exit();
  
 }
?>

Comment: It is now adding something to the database, though not in the right places. Last Name is going into first name, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `$db` is either not an object (if it's not actually NULL), or `$db` doesn't have a function named `exec`.

I recommend you verify that your connection to the database is successful, and verify that `$db` is the connection object. Verify that `exec` is a valid function for the object.

Also, your code appears to be vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.  (We don't see that the arguments passed to the function have been "escaped" to be safe for inclusion in SQL text.) We much prefer to see a **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure what I can change to get this to work from this answer. I am in a development environment with this code and hope that you realize it isn't he finished product. Thank you, but please tell me what you mean for me to change to get the code to work.